Pronunciation rule
Is there any rule about the pitch accent of nouns resulting from i-adjectives plus the suffixes み and さ?
For instance 長い 長さ 長み

For ～さ, traditionally mostly:

accentless i-adjectives: accentless (あかい{LHH} → あかさ{LHH})
accented i-adjectives:

3 or less morae: accent on 1st mora (ない{HL} → なさ{HL}, さむい{LHL} → さむさ {HLL})
4 or more morae: accent on same mora (きたない{LHHL} → きたなさ{LHHL}, おもしろい{LHHHL} → おもしろさ{LHHHL})


compounded: follow the last element

くろい{LHL} → くろさ{HLL} > はらぐろい{LHHHL} → はらぐろさ{LHHLL}
suffixes: usually 1st mora ～らしい{LHL} → ～らしさ{HLL}, ～っぽい{LHL} → っぽさ{LHL}, ～ない (negative) → ～なさ{HL}



where the accent may be put one more mora back due to vowel devoicing, most notably ～しい{HL} accepts both ～しさ{HL} and ～〇しさ{HLL}.
Only one exception I know is おおきい{LHHL} → おおきさ{LHHH}.
So, you have to know the correct accent of the adjective's dictionary form, and it is in fact very confused in Tokyo. Probably due to this, I could say you can practically pronounce any ～さ nouns with either -1 (…〇〇さ{HHL}) or -2 (…〇〇さ{HLL}) pattern without sounding too much unnatural in speech (and the accentless pattern is also versatile for 3-5 mora words IMO). Exceptions are those otherwise homophonic pairs: あつさ{HLL} (heat) vs. あつさ{LHH} (thickness).
On the other hand, ～み is basically always accentless. A small portion of words also has alternative ultimate accent (尾高), though.

PS
Among your examples, 長み is no more in the modern vocabulary, but recently ～み has seen a sudden revival as an element of slang expressions, so you can perhaps use it in some jokes.

Generally speaking if み attaches to a 平板 i-adjective then the resulting word is 平板. If it attaches to 起伏then generally the result is 尾高 but 平板 and -2 中高 is also pretty common. So usually 平板 is pretty safe as Broccoli forest has mentioned.

As regards さ suffix, I think it must be considered as an inflectional suffix, 動詞の接尾辞, so it leaves the i-adjective as such and not convert it in a real noun. So I thought that the accent rule for i-adjectives should be still valid: heiban pattern for heiban i-adjectives; accent on penultimate root mora for nakadaka i-adjectives. I tested for a few i-adjectives and it apparently works. Can someone possibly confirm this hypothesis?
